# How to preserve a hyperlink on Android SMS message

Tags: php, android, twilio

I am sending an SMS message to an Android phone using Twilio.

The domain has a hypen in it.  e.g. http://my-domain.com

When the SMS message arrives on Android, only the initial portion of the text is included in the hyperlink.

So in the above example the hyperlink is `"http://my"`

How is it possible to escape a hyperlink being send to android?  I am using the PHP Twilio client.

Comment: To a large extent, what is and is not part of the link is up to the SMS client, not Android.

Comment: An SMS is simple text. How any given phone interprets that is well beyond your control.

Answer (score 1):

It might be you done any small mistake. And, it not depend on android or iOS.
I also tried and it worked as its not specific to Android or iOS.

```
    <?php

        require '../Services/Twilio.php'; // Include the Twilio PHP library

        $version = "2010-04-01"; // Twilio REST API version

        // Set our Account SID and AuthToken
        $sid = 'yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy';
        $token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';


        $client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token, $version); //initialise the Twilio client
        $message = 'http://my-domain.com';
        try {
            // Initiate a new outbound call
            $call = $client->account->messages->create(array( 
    'To' => "+YYYYYYYYYY", 
    'From' => "+1XXXXXXXXXX", 
    'Body' => $message,   
));
            echo 'TWILIO SMS';
            echo 'Sending.... ';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
```

Here, my code. From this am getting this url as same in SMS from Twilio.

You please check your code once. And, I hope my code will help you.